# How to read environment variables value from /proc file system in QNX?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

I want to read an environment variable value of a running process from `/proc` file system.
I could not find `/proc/<pid>/environ` file on QNX.
I know how we can read it from getenv API but I want to read it from `/proc/<pid>`.

Comment: `/proc` is a very architecture-specific thing. If QNX doesn't have this feature, you're SOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there's no easy-to-use API on QNX for accessing another program's environment programmatically.

If your application permits, the easiest solution is to use QNX's [`pidin`](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/p/pidin.html)  -- run `pidin -p <pid> environment` to dump the environment to the standard output.

If you cannot spawn additional processes, what I believe `pidin` is doing internally is something like:

- Use [`DCMD_PROC_INFO`](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.cookbook/topic/s3_procfs_DCMD_PROC_INFO.html) to retrive the virtual address of the initial stack of the target process;
- [Open the target processes' address space](https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.cookbook/topic/s3_procfs_Operations.html) via `/proc/<pid>/as`, seek to the inital stack address, and parse through it:

  - First word is `argc`
  - Next is `argv`, so skip past that many char*s, plus one
  - Next is an array of char*s to the environment variables, terminated by a null; you can seek to each address and read the contents.